# Неверный вывод производной

Tags: массивы

Программа вычисляет значение функции и ее производной в заданной точке.
Если степень многочлена <=4, то все вычисляется правильно, однако когда степень >4, то программа выводит в качестве ответа большое отрицательное число.
Когда дебажу, то все считает верно при любой степени многочлена.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
        srand(time(NULL));
        int N = 1 + rand() % 7;
        double* A = new double [N];
        int i, znach_V_Tochke;
        int result = 0, res_Deriv = 0;


        cout << "Степень многочлена = " << N << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++){

            A[i] = rand()%7;    
        }

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
            cout << A[i] << " * x^" << i << endl;
        }

        cout << "Введите значение x --> " << endl;
        cin >> znach_V_Tochke;


        for (i = N; i >= 0; --i){

            result += A[i] * pow(znach_V_Tochke, i);
        }
        cout << "Значение многочлена в точке " << znach_V_Tochke << " = " << result << endl;

        for (i = N; i >= 0; --i){

            res_Deriv += A[i] * i * pow(znach_V_Tochke, i - 1);
        }
        cout << "Значение многочлена производной в точке " << znach_V_Tochke << " = " << res_Deriv << endl;

        delete[] A;

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: На стандарт c++ не похоже, добавте метку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, при вычислениях значения многочлена и производной вы используете значение коэффициента `A[N]`, которое у вас вообще лежит за пределами массива. Вообще-то у многочлена степени `N` должен быть `N + 1` коэффициент (включая свободный член). При вычислениях вы об этом знаете, но при выделении памяти и инициализации массива `A` вы почему-то об этом "не знали". Из неопределенного значения `A[N]` и лезет ваше "большое число". Для любой степени многочлена.

Бросается в глаза, что при выдаче многочлена степени `N` на экран у вас старшая степень всегда равна `N-1`. Это с каких пор такой многочлен стал назваться многочленом степени `N`?

Во-вторых, для точек подальше от `[-1, 1]` значение вашего многочлена при большой степени могут запросто переполнить тип `int`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, значение многочлена в точке и производная должны быть типа `double`.

Во вторых, при i равном 0, у вас при вычислении производной зачем-то свободный член многочлена умножается на x^-1, что не корректно. Ваш цикл должен бежать до 1, а не до 0.